# Mac Help Indexer Dev Tool

Tags: indexer, helpfile

I'm looking into the Mac .help file and wondered if anyone had written one and if they knew of any pieces of software that aided in this?

[*]Help Indexer
 (/Developer/Applications/Utilities)
Can't find it at https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ or Xcode.app/Contents

I'm happy writing the HTML files it's just the admin involved for the other files I thought could be better suited to automation or an app.

Links
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/authoring_help/authoring_help_book.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000903-CH206-CIHEHEAC
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/user_help_intro/user_assistance_intro.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OnlineHelp/OnlineHelp.html

Blogs
http://blog.gamecraft.org/2009/10/three-steps-to-apple-help-part-1/
http://blog.gamecraft.org/2009/11/three-steps-to-apple-help-part-2/

http://devzone.touchdude.com/step-step-create-apple-help-your-cocoa-xcode-application

Apps
http://www.indoition.com/online-help-authoring-tools-survey.htm

I've used Help Scribble (http://www.helpscribble.com) in the past for Windows applications just wondered if there was something similar on the mac to create a .help file for my app.

Thanks

*Cross Posts*
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12297
http://raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=22376

Comment: Help Crafter - http://www.putercraft.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in the Downloads section under "Auxiliary Tools For Xcode 7"
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/?q=auxiliary

[image: Auxiliary Tools For Xcode 7]